# How to make this Card Responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make the card-2 component responsive but its not working. What i did is put the card-2 component in `display-flex` and then put `@media` query. but when i am shrinking the page is showing full fledged site. Also I  faced problems during responsive on my site.

`Data.js` is a data file which stores `name`, `text`, `id`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "../Styles/Testimonials.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { Data } from "./Data";

// const Testimonials = () => {
//   return (
//     <div>
//       <b style={{ fontWeight: 100 }}>Testimonials</b>
//     </div>
//   );
// };

// export default Testimonials;
export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <b style={{ fontWeight: 100 }}>Testimonials</b>
        <h1 className="cutomer" style={{ fontSize: "50px" }}>
          What Customers Says about us
        </h1>{" "}
        <br />
        <br />
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {Data.map((item) => {
            const imageUrl = `https://picsum.photos/20${item.id}`;

            return (
              <>
                <div className="card-2">
                  <img src={imageUrl} alt="" />

                  <h2>Some Title</h2>
                  <h4 style={{ fontWeight: 300 }}>{item.text}</h4>
                  <h3 style={{ letterSpacing: 2 }}>{item.name}</h3>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Testimonial.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;500&display=swap');

.card-2 {
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* height: auto; */
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */

}

.cutomer {
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    /* animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    50% {
        margin-left: 300px;
    }

    100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .card-2 {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        width: auto;
        border: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have enclosed the card section in the Slider. Try to update the settings of your slider to make it responsive.
Also, make sure to use the `key` attribute while mapping the lists of elements/items.

```js
const settings = {
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 400,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }]
};
```

Comment: i want to show only 1 at a time when the page start shrinking but its not happening